# Adding clickablility to LI elements that are dynamically added to web page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

The code I have so far is using the Google Maps API to take in something the user enters, looks it up on the map, and then appends search they entered to the right of the map. The one part I am missing is that for the searches on the right, I have to make them be able to be clicked and upon click they go to the marker on the map. I was wondering if anyone had any advice or hints to help me figure it out, since I have tried a lot of different things (for some reason using the .on('click',...) wouldn't work properly).

Thank you!
.html file:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <title>Simple Map</title>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
    <script src = "project2.js"></script>  


    <link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "project2.css">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
  </head>


  <body>
    <form>
    <div>
      <label> Address: </label>
      <input id = "address" type = "text">
      <input id = "submit" type = "button" value = "Add"> 
      <br><br>
    </div>
    </form>
    <section>
      <ul>
      </ul>
    </section>

    <div id="map"></div>
    <script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyAGysAFeYIRV2qqMeEcnehH9igIaSYxvvs&callback=initMap"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

.js file:

```
function initMap() {
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
            center: {lat: 41.083, lng: -74.174},
            zoom: 8
        });
        var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

        document.getElementById('submit').addEventListener('click', function() { 

            showAddress(geocoder, map);
            //getLinks();

        });
    }

    function showAddress(geocoder, newMap)
    {
        var address = document.getElementById('address').value;
        //console.log(address);
        $('<li/>').addClass('list').text(address).appendTo('ul');

        geocoder.geocode({'address': address}, function(results, status) {
            if (status === 'OK') {
                newMap.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    map:newMap,
                    position: results[0].geometry.location
                });
            }
            else {
                alert('Geocode was not successful for reason: ' + status);
            }
        });
    }

    /*
    function getLinks()
    {
        console.log("hey");
        $('#elements').on('click', 'li', function(){
            alert($(this).text());
            console.log("hey2");
        });
    }*/
```

.css file:

```
input[type = text]
{
    width: 375px;
}
li {
    list-style-type: none;
    width: 450px;
    border-style: solid;
    padding: 0.3em;
    margin-left: 475px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-bottom: .5em;

}
.list {
    background-color: #8E8989;

}
#map {
    position:absolute;
    top: 50px;
    height:60%;
    width:40%;
   /* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
   * element that contains the map. */
}
html, body{
    height: 100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:5px;
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: try `$('body').on('click', 'li', function() {
    // do something
});` let me know what comes out

Comment: It worked! Thank you. I was wondering why that worked instead of $('li').on('click', 'li', ...)?

Comment: @A K I am adding it as an answer, please accept it :)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest adding an `id` to the `<ul>`, and attach a `click` event listener to it instead of the dynamically created `<li>`.

For example:

`<ul id="address-list">`

Then in javascript, use:

```
$("#address-list").on("click",".list",function(){
    /* Do something */
})
```

Answer (score 0):

To add event on dynamically generated elements you need to use something like

```
$('body').on('click', 'li', function() { // do something });
```